# PHP e base de dados

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Boas, estou a elaborar um site e preciso de armazenar numa base de dados um ficheiro inserido/carregado pelo utilizador. 
Qual o tipo de dados que devo atribuir ao campo?

Comment: Da uma olhada neste link -> http://blog.fabianobento.com.br/2009/09/armazenar-arquivos-em-modo-binario-mysql-usando-php/

Comment: Usa BLOB ou VARCHAR, depende do tamanho do arquivo.

Comment: tentei usar o MEDIUMBLOB mas nao reconhece o tipo de dados

Comment: Use o VARCHAR e defina um bom tamanho para ele, o DB vai armazenar uma referencia para o seu arquivo e não o arquivo em si.

Comment: o que quer dizer com a frase "tentei usar o MEDIUMBLOB mas nao reconhece o tipo de dados" ?

Answer (score 1):

Use VARCHAR colocando o caminho fisico no servidor. Faça uma analise de toda a aplicação para ver se não é necessário ter um tabela apenas para arquivos, assim você poderia colocar mais informações sobre os arquivos nesta tabela.

Como:

- caminho fisico no servidor
- url do arquivo
- tamanho do arquivo

Dentre outras várias informações que poderia vir do arquivo.

Answer (score 0):

Use um VARCHAR e armazene apenas o caminho físico do arquivo no seu servidor

Answer (score 0):

Caso o link do ficheiro for completo, com http://... use `VARCHAR` com Tamanho `250` (o máximo suportado em um campo VARCHAR). Caso você venha ver que o campo é muito extenso e ultrapasse 250 caracteres, use `TEXT` que suporta muitos caracteres.

Comment: O  tipo VARCHAR é 0 ~ 255 para versões até 5.0.3. Acima dessa versão é 0 ~ 65535.  O tipo CHAR é mais apropriado.. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html